# Adding to the shortcode redirection after submitting the form

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode, contact-form-7

I use the plugin and whether it is possible to add a shortcode redirection after successful submitting the form? Like this:

```
[contact-form-7 id="117" title="test form" on_sent_ok="location='http://example.com/page/pa2j43452w2';"]
```

If you do not like such a modification done? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally place the: `on_sent_ok: "location.replace('page-to-go-to');"` in the additional settings field of the form and not within the shortcode. For me that works like a charm.
Here's a post about is from Contact form 7: http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/